Time Series plot with event annotation using geom_rect
I would like to reverse scale but only for geom_line as sec_axis. And also, why geom_rect doesn't appear in my plot. Here is my recent code below :
library(rsoi)
dummy <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("1981-01-01"), as.Date("2010-12-01"), by = "month"),
                    Percentage = runif(360, min = 0, max = 100))
dummy$index <- runif(360, min = -1, max =1)
# Download ENSO DATA
library(dplyr)
enso <- rsoi::download_oni()
enso_data <- enso %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Year >=1981 & Year <=2010)
enso_data$Month <- factor(enso_data$Month, levels=month.abb)
# Pastikan bahwa kolom Date memiliki format Date
enso_data$Date <- as.Date(enso_data$Date)
# Urutkan data berdasarkan tanggal
enso_data <- enso_data %>% arrange(Date)
# Create a new column based on the occurrence of El Niño, La Niña, or neutral years
df_rect <- enso_data %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize(x1=first(Date), x2=last(Date), phase=first(phase))
ggplot(data=dummy, aes(x=Date, y=Percentage))+
  geom_col() +
  geom_line(aes(y= index), col = "red")+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, fill=phase),
            ymin=min(dummy$Percentage), ymax=max(dummy$Percentage),
            alpha=0.2, data=df_rect, inherit.aes=F)+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  labs(x=" ",  y="Area (%)") +
  coord_cartesian(expand=F) +
  theme_minimal() %+replace% theme(legend.position="bottom")

Here is my expected plot, where area as geom_bar and index as an reverse goem_line, and also add an geom_rect:


From a visualization standpoint, this is hard to read accurately. Why would the bars be read from the top and moving downward? One of the many ways secondary axes can mislead people is by conflating the relationship between two variables; here that relationship isn't even direct, so why not use two charts?

Here's one approach to the first question. Also, see these other SO questions that would be helpful here link 1 and link 2.
library(tidyverse)

# Create the dummy data
dummy <- data.frame(
  Date = seq(as.Date("1981-01-01"), as.Date("2010-12-01"), by = "month"),
  Percentage = runif(360, min = 0, max = 100)
)

dummy$index <- runif(360, min = -1, max = 1)

# Define the y-axis limits
ylim.primary <- c(0, 100)
ylim.secondary <- c(1, -1)

# Calculate the transformation parameters
b <- diff(ylim.secondary) / diff(ylim.primary)
a <- ylim.secondary[1] - b * ylim.primary[1]

# Create the plot
ggplot(data = dummy, aes(x = Date, y = Percentage)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_line(aes(y = (index - ylim.secondary[1]) / b + ylim.primary[1]), color = "red", linewidth = 1) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    trans = 'reverse',
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (.- ylim.primary[1]) * b + ylim.secondary[1], name = 'Index')
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme_minimal()


Created on 2024-05-30 with reprex v2.1.0
